# Unable to assemble mdadm array due to lack of errors

Tags: linux, debian, software-raid, mdadm, debian-jessie

My virtual machine host system is running Debian 8.4. I had to restart the system yesterday and did not yet manage to get my `mdadm` array up and running again. I can boot up normally, but no array (or error) waits for me.

All raid drives are connected by using a pcie sata extension card.
The drives are all there, but `mdadm` seems to ignore them. Also, I did not find a single error message that might be related to my problem in either `dmesg` output or any `mdadm` command I tried.

I am ready to post `dmesg` data, but I do not know how to filter irrelevant lines (no `mdadm` output in there anyway).

---

Usually, `lsblk` would list the mdadm partitions and stuff on my drives, but not today.

```
jejanim@vault:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  55.9G  0 disk
sdb      8:16   0  55.9G  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0 447.1G  0 disk
└─sdc1   8:33   0   447G  0 part /mnt/music
sdd      8:48   0  55.9G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   0   487M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdd2   8:50   0  53.7G  0 part /
└─sdd3   8:51   0   1.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sde      8:64   0 238.5G  0 disk
└─sde1   8:65   0 238.5G  0 part
sdf      8:80   0  59.6G  0 disk
sdg      8:96   0 119.2G  0 disk
└─sdg1   8:97   0 119.2G  0 part
```

---

Examining all the drives yields something like this for all of the 4 raid drives:

```
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 2e3a29fc:12e40f9c:7b6f57d7:b00b62cc
           Name : vault:0  (local to host vault)
  Creation Time : Mon Aug  3 19:32:06 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 250004480 (119.21 GiB 128.00 GB)
     Array Size : 175747584 (167.61 GiB 179.97 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 117165056 (55.87 GiB 59.99 GB)
    Data Offset : 62464 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=62376 sectors, after=132839424 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b1b45ac6:b0acac1e:fc46cdb5:00ac85d6

    Update Time : Thu Apr  7 20:24:20 2016
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 9a815dbc - correct
         Events : 94417

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

---

Seems okay? Well, attempt to assemble it:

```
jejanim@vault:~$ sudo mdadm --assemble --uuid=2e3a29fc:12e40f9c:7b6f57d7:b00b62cc --verbose /dev/md0
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
```

`mdadm` is not particularly chatty about that one, and a cat /proc/mdstat reveals:

```
jejanim@vault:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>
```

---

Do you have any hint on how to assemble the array again?

Answer (score 0):

Okay it seems mdadm just needed a smarter user that fully understands how to use it.

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 --verbose /dev/sd[abc] /dev/sdg
```

did the trick.